# Jenkins run aborted by anonymous: The user id should be always non-null thanks to DefaultUserCanonicalIdResolver

Tags: java, jenkins, build, anonymous

I accidentally modified the security settings without knowing, so we had to wipe the whole member access list and restart. There is now an anonymous user (which is new - we used to have an "admin" user). It seems the anonymous user in Jenkins is aborting jobs and this error is displayed:

```
FATAL: The user id should be always non-null thanks to DefaultUserCanonicalIdResolver
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The user id should be always non-null thanks to DefaultUserCanonicalIdResolver
    at hudson.model.User.get(User.java:401)
    at hudson.model.User.get(User.java:362)
    at hudson.model.User.get(User.java:481)
    at jenkins.model.CauseOfInterruption$UserInterruption.getUser(CauseOfInterruption.java:86)
    at jenkins.model.CauseOfInterruption$UserInterruption.print(CauseOfInterruption.java:95)
    at hudson.model.Executor.recordCauseOfInterruption(Executor.java:276)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1755)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
ERROR: Post-build steps failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.model.JobProperty.getDescriptor(JobProperty.java:105)
    at hudson.model.JobProperty.getDescriptor(JobProperty.java:79)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.toMap(Descriptor.java:973)
    at hudson.model.Job.getProperties(Job.java:558)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:196)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1785)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you managing your Jenkins server with a Configuration Management tool like Puppet? We found that one of our Puppet Jenkins modules liked to run Jenkins admin commands using CLI remoting plus the admin user. When our users list changed and the admin user disappeared, the commands would still succeed thanks to anonymous auth, but Jenkins panicked when it was asked to authenticate using a non-existent user.

To make things more fun, Puppet was running as a service, scheduled for every 30 minutes, so we got this error over and over again in the logs.

There are a few options here:

- If you have to have it, re-add the 'admin' user.
- (Low-rent solution) Do not run your Configuration Management tool as a service on the Jenkins box, instead kick it with one-off commands. This won't get rid of the underlying issue causing this stack trace (trying to authenticate as 'admin' when there is no such user), but it might help to make the logs quieter when diagnosing the fault.
- Change your Configuration Management script to configure Jenkins some other way, such that it avoids tickling user authentication.